# How to have app automatically send log file to support?

Tags: vb6, windows-xp, logging, error-logging

In order to manage the errors coming from a particular client I am thinking about having the app send the current error log file to me, perhaps when it starts up.

What would the best way to achieve this in a VB6/XP environment?

Email might be easy but I imagine that could fire off all sorts of anti-virus/firewall protections.

Connecting to a webserver might be better.  Would the app still have to open up the Windows firewall in this case?

Comment: Any sort of connection from their computer to yours will trigger a Windows firewall, I think. The only thing that might not trigger a Windows firewall response would be if you tried to do an HTTP request on port 80, but even then it would probably trigger Windows firewall. The firewall is supposed to make sure your app can't do anything weird. If it let you do HTTP requests without warning the user, for example, then a malicious program could download bad files with HTTP GET requests and hurt the user's computer. So anything you do will probably trigger Windows Firewall.

Comment: @moowiz2020: do you just have to add an exception in the Windows firewall for your app and the required port?

Comment: Essentially yes. So sending an email or an HTTP post would be easy, I think. Once you try to send an email or a HTTP request, a Windows Firewall window would pop up asking the user if it wanted to let your application access the internet. Note that I haven't really tested any of this, so there might be issues with it.

Comment: Even sending HTTP over port 80 may be blocked by a corporate firewall as they sometimes route HTTP over another port. Your best option is to use the local machine mail client to send your email - but you cannot guarantee this will be able to occur silently.

Comment: @MattWilko: if you use the local mail client can you suppress messages/confirmations and can you prevent emails appearing in Sent Mail?

Comment: @CraigJ - No you can't guarantee that you will be able to suppress messages - this is generally a security feature because people want to know that email is being sent on their behalf.

Comment: @moowiz2020: Windows firewall up to WinXP doesn't have outbound rules, so no filtering happens on outgoing connections. Malicious programs have to have admin privileges to "hurt" user's computer. With admin rights malware can hurt you w/o downloading anything, `del` command can do miracles.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `XMLHTTP` to upload clients error logs like this: http://wqweto.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/vb6-using-wininet-to-post-binary-file/

```
Private Sub pvPostFile(sUrl As String, sFileName As String, Optional ByVal bAsync As Boolean)
    Const STR_BOUNDARY  As String = "3fbd04f5-b1ed-4060-99b9-fca7ff59c113"
    Dim nFile           As Integer
    Dim baBuffer()      As Byte
    Dim sPostData       As String

    '--- read file
    nFile = FreeFile
    Open sFileName For Binary Access Read As nFile
    If LOF(nFile) > 0 Then
        ReDim baBuffer(0 To LOF(nFile) - 1) As Byte
        Get nFile, , baBuffer
        sPostData = StrConv(baBuffer, vbUnicode)
    End If
    Close nFile
    '--- prepare body
    sPostData = "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=""uploadfile""; filename=""" & Mid$(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, "\") + 1) & """" & vbCrLf & _
        "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
        sPostData & vbCrLf & _
        "--" & STR_BOUNDARY & "--"
    '--- post
    With CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "POST", sUrl, bAsync
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" & STR_BOUNDARY
        .Send pvToByteArray(sPostData)
    End With
End Sub

Private Function pvToByteArray(sText As String) As Byte()
    pvToByteArray = StrConv(sText, vbFromUnicode)
End Function
```

Comment: Sounds like there is an issue with which HTTP agent to use. You are saying there are deployment issues. Out of Microsoft.XMLHTTP, WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 and WinInet, which would you recommend?

Comment: `XMLHTTP` is often getting corrupted, but `WinHttpRequest` is not available on older OSes. I'm using `XMLHTTP` now as it's more compatible. Doubt users can stand long without AJAX in browsers.

Comment: @wqw Consider adding some sample code to avoid a link-only answer.